# How to build a classpath for Source Code which is dependant on many third party packages

Tags: java, eclipse

I have ONLY source code available for few jars that were compiled in Java 1.5

Not I want them to be packaged in Java 1.8

So I import the code in a zip file to Eclipse project, but there are lot of compilation issues on imports, because of dependency on 3rd party jars like commons-lang, or gwt etc...

Is there a way I can automate the process of building the classpath?

And more basic question.... why a JAR compiled in Java 1.5 not usable in Java 1.8

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: suppose the project does not have a `pom.xml`(Maven project) , I think you need to add the required jar's manually to the class path.